# Adding an msi file with the installer created in install shield

Tags: c#, installation, installshield-le

I want to add another application that is installed on the user PC with my setup . 
It is possible to wrapup both in install shield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [WiX Tooset](http://wixtoolset.org/) if you need to build a custom installation package.